# Displaying youtube video thumbnail in my android application

Tags: android, youtube

In my app i am trying to play some youtube videos. So in the home screen my videos will be displayed in a listview. I need the thumbnail of the videos. How i can get the thumbnail of the youtube videos through java code. Please see the sample scree shot TED app. [image]